# Is there a way to block/close iframes using seleium?

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a downloader from Instagram. This program gets URLs from top Instagram posts in a given hashtag and inputs them into a downloader. The issue is that a popup iframe ad always appears over the download button when the website is first loaded. This throws an error that the button cannot be clicked because the iframe will be clicked.

This is for Python Selenium running Chrome driver. I have tried to run a filter that finds iframes and goes back to the main page:

```
all_iframes = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
if len(all_iframes) > 0:
       self.browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

This did not work, I also tried to get the XPath to the X-button on the ad, but the ID changes every time, so I cannot be clicked or identified.

```
#get the website
        for link in self.links:
            self.browser.get('https://downloadgram.com/')
            time.sleep(5)

#this is the x button click iframe I tried, but the XPath changes
            all_iframes = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
            if len(all_iframes) > 0:
                xButton = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="id3019a64023cross3019a64023"]')
                xButton.click()

#inputs the URL from array links[] into download box
            input = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="url"]')
            input.clear()
            input.send_keys(link)
            time.sleep(1)

#clicks download button
            download = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
            download.click()
            time.sleep(1)

#clicks confirm button 
            actuallyDownload = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@target='_blank']")
            actuallyDownload.click()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I expect the code to download the pictures at the url, but I get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <input type="submit" value="Download" class="button"> is not clickable at point (451, 446). Other element would receive the click:
```

the website (turn off adblock to see add) https://downloadgram.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to close the pop up with following code.Please try that.

```
browser.get('https://downloadgram.com/')
time.sleep(5)

element=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@id,'id')]" and "//div[starts-with(@style,'position:absolute !important;height:20px !important;width:20px !important;top:3px !important;left:3px !important;background-image:url(data:image/png;')]")
arrt=element.get_attribute("id") 
print(arrt)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Let me know if it works.Good Luck.

Comment: This worked great. I never thought of the [starts-with], great idea!

Comment: Although sometimes the add doesn't appear, so I just said- if element: execute_script